# Making fruit syrup less viscous while retaining flavor

Tags: fruit, syrup

I'm making snow cones from real fruit syrup that I'm making myself - the problem is that the fruit syrup comes out too viscous and it tends to set on top of the snow cone ice.  Is there anyway to make sure the flavoring is just as sweet, but less viscous?  The fruit I'm having the most trouble with right now is strawberry.

And related to this (especially strawberry) is there a good way to strain out small particles.  I wish I could shove the strawberry syrup through a coffee filter, but I don't know how this can be done.

Comment: For the filtering, does a fine mesh strainer not work?

Answer (score 1):

To thin your syrup, add more water to your syrup; it will become thinner without reducing sweetness that much.  Then add a touch of artificial sweetener to restore any lost sweetness.

To strain your syrup, you can use multiple layers of cheesecloth, a fine chinois, or a coffee filter in the bottom of a strainer or small colander.  Use a spatula, spoon, or ladle to help press the syrup through the filter. Using heated syrup will allow it to flow more readily through the filter, while still removing particles.